# Term reference is not available as a contextual filter for a View. Why not?

Tags: views

I have a commerce product of type Album. On this content type is a taxonomy term reference. This term is from the vocabulary 'Our Artist'. In other words, every album gets tagged w/ the artist name that comes from the 'Our Artists' vocabulary.

I'm trying to create a view that groups together all of an artist albums. I want to use this taxonomy term as a contextual filter. But it is not showing up as an option in the contextual filters list. Can someone explain why?

Comment: You might need to add it as a relationship first.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Niall's comment, you will want to add the taxonomy relationship. In a view that I created recently, I used the `Content: Taxonomy terms on node` relationship. Once I added it, `Content: Has taxonomy term` became an available option under **Filter criteria**.

That is only one way of doing it. There are a few different taxonomy relationships which serve unique purposes. I'd experiment with them to see what fits your needs.